# VisualStudio MFC CListCtrl SetItemText fails

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I created a MFC Visual Studio Project with a CListCtrl. I added some items in the CDialog class like:

```
int l_iItem = m_listCtrl.InsertItem(LVIF_TEXT|LVIF_STATE, counter, someString, 0, LVIS_SELECTED, 0, 0);       
m_listCtrl.SetItemText( l_iItem, 1, blockHexChar );  
m_listCtrl.SetItemText( l_iItem, 2, description);
```

This works fine.

Afterwards i want to edit a subitem (over double click event). Works also fine.

If the editing is finished (this is in the CListCtrl class),

```
OnEndLabelEdit(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
```

will be called. It looks like this

```
LV_DISPINFO *plvDispInfo = (LV_DISPINFO *)pNMHDR;   
LV_ITEM *plvItem = &plvDispInfo->item;
if (plvItem->pszText != NULL)   
{
  bool res = SetItemText(plvItem->iItem, plvItem->iSubItem, plvItem->pszText);
}
```

I always getting 0 back, so the SetItemText is failing.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Cheers ehmkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input, but the problem was in the MESSAGE_MAP(....) in CDialog class.

I have a member here, which holds the list and I directly mapped to the CListCtrl Class.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CPeriDialog, CDialog)
  ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ENDLABELEDIT, IDC_LIST1, &CListCtrl::OnEndLabelEdit)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Now I made a wrapper function which forward the event to the right object.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CPeriDialog, CDialog)
  ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ENDLABELEDIT, IDC_LIST1, &CPeriDialog::EndEdit)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Function simple looks like this

```
void CPeriDialog::EndEdit(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
  m_listCtrl.OnEndLabelEdit(pNMHDR, pResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to post yourself a user-defined message (`WM_USER+NNN`) using `PostMessage` from within `OnEndLabelEdit`. Change label in response to that message.

Answer (score 0):

[LVN_ENDLABELEDIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774814(v=vs.85).aspx) passes a pointer to [NMLVDISPINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774780(v=vs.85).aspx) through lParam.  I think you're looking at the wrong structure when processing the notification.  Using the class wizard to generate the event handler in VS2013 gives

```
void CMFCApplication6Dlg::OnLvnEndlabeleditList1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
    {
    NMLVDISPINFO *pDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    *pResult = 0;
    }
```